# Recreating machine-id kills DHCP in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dhcp, ubuntu-20.04

I am having a bit of an odd problem with an Ubuntu template I am working on. Basically, doing "echo -n > /etc/machine-id" for template sanitation purposes to have the system recreate it on next boot kills the system's DHCP client (as in, no new leases can be obtained after the reboot). I am aware that systemd-networkd uses machine-id instead of the MAC address in it's DHCP requests, so my question is actually two-fold:

1. Why wouldn't the regenerated machine-id "just work" for DHCP purposes?
2. Once the problem has manifested itself after a reboot, even adding "dhcp-identifier: mac" to my netplan configuration doesn't seem to solve it. Huh?

What's going on and how do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Have you run `systemd-machine-id-setup` after killing the old machine id ?

Comment: What does your DHCP client have to say about it? Run `systemctl set-environment SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug`, then restart systemd-networkd.

Comment: I don't think I've tried systemd-machine-id-setup because the machine-id clearly is there after the reboot, so it is regenerated by *something*. Does the matter in which the machine-id is regenerated matter for DHCP purposes?

Comment: Here's what happens:

1) If I "echo -n > /etc/machine-id", a new (checked contents) machine-id is created on next boot, but DHCP doesn't work.

2) If I "rm /etc/machine-id" and reboot, it's not automatically recreated

2.5) If I run "systemd-machine-id-setup" manually, it does get recreated and repopulated. But DHCP still doesn't work.

As soon as I roll back my VMWare snapshot back to the pristine "autoinstall just finished" state which obviously sets machine-id back to whatever the installer had decided it to be, DHCP works again.

Comment: Solved. I am a moron: the DHCP was full.